# PostgreSQL \d Commands: Any way to "select" only one column?

Tags: postgresql, psql

Unlike most SQL derivatives, PostgreSQL doesn't use the traditional `DESCRIBE TABLE foo` syntax; it uses `\d foo` (from the `psql` interpreter).

That's great, except that (especially when I have `psql` open in a terminal with limited width) it can be difficult to read the output of `\d`, because there are a bunch of columns and a bunch of values, and they can be hard to line everything up.

So, my simple question is, when using `\d` and its variants (eg. `\df`), is there any way to only get one column of output back?  For instance, if I do `\d users`, instead of getting:

```
                                       Table "public.users"
   Column   |           Type           | Collation | Nullable |              Default              
------------+--------------------------+-----------+----------+-----------------------------------
 id         | integer                  |           | not null | nextval('users_id_seq'::regclass)
 created_at | timestamp with time zone |           | not null | CURRENT_TIMESTAMP
 updated_at | timestamp with time zone |           | not null | CURRENT_TIMESTAMP
 username   | character varying(255)   |           | not null | 
 title      | character varying(500)   |           |          | 
 first_name | character varying(50)    |           |          | 
 last_name  | character varying(50)    |           |          |
```

is there some way (eg. `\d users Column`, although this doesn't work) to get just:

```
                                         Table "public.users"
   Column   |           
------------+
 id         |
 created_at |
 updated_at |
 username   |
 first_name |
 last_name  |
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

### Actual subset of `\d` output

Yes. Pop the hood by setting [`ECHO-HIDDEN` to `on`](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/app-psql.html#APP-PSQL-OPTION-ECHO-HIDDEN) and throw away anything you don't like, grabbing only what you want. Every individual piece of what that output is constructed from, will work fine on its own.

> `-E`  `--echo-hidden`
> Echo the actual queries generated by `\d` and other backslash commands. You can use this to study psql's internal operations. This is equivalent to setting the variable `ECHO_HIDDEN` to `on`.

PostgreSQL doesn't understand `\d`. It's an internal meta-command of `psql`, which is a client like any other. The data you see is a result of the client issuing a series of queries and gluing their output together - the setting above lets you learn what those queries were. You can use them "by hand" or even rearrange them to better fit your purpose.

---

### Terminal width

You might want to check out [`expanded` mode](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/app-psql.html#APP-PSQL-META-COMMAND-PSET-EXPANDED). `psql` offers multiple [output formats](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/app-psql.html#APP-PSQL-META-COMMAND-PSET-FORMAT) to select from: `wrapped` has adjustable `columns` width. You should also have control over your terminal screen buffer layout in its properties - there, you could crank up the width and whenever something's too wide, you'll scroll right if you want or just leave it sticking out, off-screen.

---

### Querying structures/schema

There's SQL-standard compliant [`information_schema`](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/information-schema.html) namespace, and in it, there's [`columns`](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/infoschema-columns.html) view. You can go there directly:

```sql
select column_name from information_schema.columns
where table_schema='public' and table_name='users';
```

The views in that schema point to the same place `psql` gets the list of columns for tables and views when you run `\d`. The actual data is in the [system catalog](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/ddl-schemas.html#DDL-SCHEMAS-CATALOG) which `psql` queries directly.

Answer (score 1):

You should check the command [`\gdesc`](https://git.postgresql.org/gitweb/?p=postgresql.git;a=commitdiff;h=49ca462eb165dea297f1f110e8eac064308e9d51)
it describes the result columns that a query will have.

So let's assume you have a simple table with three columns. It would help if you used it like below

```sql
SELECT * FROM sample_table \gdesc
```

and the result that you will receive would be

```
   Column   |            Type             
------------+-----------------------------
 id         | uuid
 created_at | timestamp without time zone
 deleted_at | timestamp without time zone
(4 rows)
```

I also encourage you to check [this thread](https://dba.stackexchange.com/questions/22362/list-all-columns-for-a-specified-table)

Comment: Can I use that with `\d`, and its variants, eg.`\df`?  For instance, could I do `\df some_function \gdesc`?

Comment: You can't. Or, you can, but with the underlying queries that `\d` uses, not with `\d` itself.

Answer (score 1):

Use the system catalog [pg_attribute](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/catalog-pg-attribute.html) directly:

```
SELECT
    attname AS column
FROM
    pg_attribute
WHERE
    attrelid = 'users'::regclass
AND 
    attnum > 0;
```

`pg_attribute` stores the column names for table like objects e.g. tables, indexes, views, etc. The `'users'::regclass` translates the table name into `oid` needed for `attrelid`. `attnum > 0` eliminates the system columns, `cmax`, `cmin`, `ctid`, etc.

Answer (score 1):

You can use `less -S` or `leafpad` or any other text editor program, that would not wrap lines, as a pager:

```
tometzky=> \setenv PAGER 'less -S'
tometzky=> \setenv PAGER leafpad
```

Or you can query information schema to get similar data with extended output:

```
tometzky=> \x on
Expanded display is on.

tometzky=> select
  column_name,
  is_nullable,
  data_type,
  character_maximum_length
from information_schema.columns
where table_name='users' and table_schema=current_schema();
```

Comment: Not trying to offend OP by assuming their platform, but those pager settings won't work on a standard Windows env. It'll let you declare that (or anything for that matter) but then fail and complain as soon as you try fetch stuff.

Comment: On windows they can use any chosen text editor too. Those are only examples. I believe things like Notepad++, Sublime Text or Visual Studio Code should work - although they will need to find the command to start it. It's not so helpful if they SSH to some Linux VM though - then `less -S` is probably the easiest, and [pspg](https://github.com/okbob/pspg) the most powerful option.